# Cisco 7301 router has no IP NAT command

Tags: networking, routing, nat

I got this Cisco 7301 router from an old co-worker and im using it to practice Cisco stuff. Right now I have my test network setup with 1 interface as my "WAN" and another interface with sub interfaces for my layer 2 switch.

I want to NAT the sub interfaces but I do not see any IP NAT command anywhere!

I have looked up and down Google and I always get the same IP NAT command from other questions and articles/blogs but I can't seem to find that command on this router at all.

Is anyone else familiar with this router? Im not quite sure why this command is not recognized anywhere. I have checked the global configuration prompt, interface configuration prompt. Nothing...

**Current Config**

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1821 bytes
!
version 12.2
service timestamps debug uptime
service timestamps log uptime
service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!

!

ip subnet-zero
ip cef
!
!
no ip domain-lookup
!
ip dhcp pool VLAN10
   network 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 10.10.10.1
   dns-server 8.8.8.8
!
ip dhcp pool VLAN20
   network 20.20.20.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 20.20.20.1
   dns-server 8.8.8.8
!
ip dhcp pool VLAN30
   network 30.30.30.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 30.30.30.1
   dns-server 8.8.8.8
!
no mpls traffic-eng auto-bw timers frequency 0
call rsvp-sync
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address dhcp
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
 no negotiation auto
 no clns route-cache
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
 no negotiation auto
 no clns route-cache
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.1
 encapsulation dot1Q 1 native
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 20.20.20.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.30
 encapsulation dot1Q 30
 ip address 30.30.30.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
 no negotiation auto
 no clns route-cache
!
ip classless
!
no ip http server
!
!
!
access-list 100 permit ip 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 100 permit ip 30.30.30.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
dial-peer cor custom
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 login local
!
!
end
```

I added the `access-list` hoping it would allow my clients on the vlans to ping `8.8.8.8` for example, or to at least allow traffic to reach the internet through my ASA but it has not worked.

**Example**

An example command that i run is `Router(config)# ip nat pool VLAN10 10.10.10.0 10.10.10.254 255.255.255.0`
The result i get is:

```
Router(config)#ip nat pool VLAN10 10.10.10.0 10.10.10.254 255.255.255.0
                    ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' 

Router(config)#
```

No matter where i run this command, the router does not recognize it.

**System Info**

```
Router#show version
Cisco IOS Software, 7301 Software (C7301-P-M), Version 12.2(25)S15, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2007 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Fri 07-Dec-07 19:21 by tinhuang

ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 12.3(4r)T4, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

 Router uptime is 2 minutes
System returned to ROM by power-on
System image file is "disk0:c7301-p-mz.122-25.S15.bin"

Cisco 7301 (NPE) processor (revision F) with 491520K/32768K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID 74838790    
SB-1 CPU at 700Mhz, Implementation 1025, Rev 0.2, 512KB L2 Cache
1 slot midplane, Version 2.0

Last reset from power-on
3 Gigabit Ethernet interfaces
509K bytes of NVRAM.

31488K bytes of ATA PCMCIA card at slot 0 (Sector size 512 bytes).
32768K bytes of Flash internal SIMM (Sector size 256K).
Configuration register is 0x2102
```

**Update**
Commands after `IP`

```
Router(config)#ip ?
Global IP configuration subcommands:
   ---- Omitted ----
  mroute                  Configure static multicast routes
  msdp                    MSDP global commands
  multicast               Global IP Multicast Commands
  multicast-routing       Enable IP multicast forwarding
  name-server             Specify address of name server to use
  nbar                    NBAR - Network Based Application Recognition
  options                 IP Options treatment
  ospf                    OSPF
  pim                     PIM global commands
  policy-list             Define IP Policy list
  prefix-list             Build a prefix list
  radius                  RADIUS configuration commands
 ---- Omitted ----
```

Comment: WHAT command? You didn't provide an example of what you are actually typing in.

Comment: I agree with Appleoddity, post the command you are entering. It would be helpful if you posted what system firmware it's running. I see 12.2 but available features depend on the actual firmware file.

Comment: updated my answer.

Comment: What other combination of the command, what does the console say is the next input after nat? It clearly isn’t “pool”

Comment: the `nat` command after `ip` does not exist, period. i updated what it shows when i type in `Router(config)# ip ?`. this is what i was trying to explain in my question, that `IP NAT...` does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a service provider image (P). NAT feature is not supported in that image. You need to get an IP image, or an Enterprise.
(c7301-is-mz or c7301-js-mz)

Comment: I thought so. Yesterday I was learning to change the software on a switch and thought I needed to do the same on the router. I had a bit of trouble finding out which image worked for this router but I'll find the one you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: Those are just the prefixes, you'll have to append whatever version like 122-25 or a newer like c7301-advipservicesk9-mz.124-4.T1.bin